Is the economy usually in general equilibrium, and what does that mean for targeting FE output?
The policy of targeting interest rates is described in terms of restoring general equilibrium in the goods, labor and asset markets i.e to bring the IS, FE, LM curves to an intersection my textbook.
In the case of LM shocks, this would mean adjusting the money supply to bring the LM curve back to the FE and IS intersection point, which would keep the interest rate stable.

In the case of an IS shock, this would mean targeting a new interest rate that brings the markets into equilibrium.

This seems to suggest that markets are usually in general equilibrium, and the fed attempts to restore it to that when shocks move it out of equilibrium. Is this the case? How frequently are markets in general equilibrium?
